# 2 counters in one for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

My output is coming wrong and I realised the reason that I am running "for loop" for "k" a value of "for loop" of j..

Running for loops for "j and k" simultaneously would solve my problem. How to do that?

```
public void yestimatedvalue() {
    for (int i = 1; i < bmarray.length; i++) {
        double g = 0;
        s = i;
        int p = missingrowcolindex(s);
        System.out.println("p::\t" + p);

        for (int j = 0; j < bmarray[i].length; j++) {
            if (j != p) {
                g = arraybeta[0][p];

                for (int k = 1; k < arraybeta.length; k++) {
                    g = g + ((bmarray[i][j]) * (arraybeta[k][p]));

                }

            }
        }
         System.out.println("g::\t" + g);
    }
}
```

output::

```
g:: 23.99999999999998

g:: 4.9999999999999964

g:: 5.999999999999995

g:: 1.0
```

Comment: I have no clue what you mean. Maybe include what your expected output should be? I also don't see "p::" anywhere in your output..but that would mean you wouldn't see any output...so

Comment: and how the output you wanted to be?

Comment: @ferozakbar 
This was the output I wanted::
g:: 25.00000000000003
g:: 4.999999999999996
g:: 25.00000000000003
g:: 0.9999999999999497

Comment: @ferozakbar: g is the variable to store the calculations and hence initialized to g=0 for every value of i

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering this question *Running for loops for "j and k" simultaneously* is:

```
for(int j=0, k=1; (j < bmarray[i].length && k < arraybeta.length); j++, k++){
  //....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! your answer helped.. now I am getting the correct output !! :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can. Java (and all c-like languages) support syntax like this:

```
for(int i=0, j=5, k=2; i < 10 && j < 50; i++, j+=2, k+=3) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hepl!! It helped me to understand the concept!

Comment: Not agree with `i<10, j<50`, it's better to not be hard coded, instead using variables or the length of arrays inside the program.